# Serving Static Content in Spring - Why Do We Need addResourceLocations Method While We Have addResourceHandler?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I was wondering why we have "`addResourceLocations`" method while we have the "`addResourceHandler`" method.

Example:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
    .addResourceLocations("/resources/css/test");
}
```

Here, I specify `"/resources/**"` while invoking the `addResourceHandler` method. Then I add the resource locations using `addResourceLocations` method and these resource locations are supposed to be the subfolders of the URL I specify in `addResourceHandler`, right? So, why is `addResourceHandler` itself just not enough to specify the resource locations itself? Isn't it gonna be a superset of location URLs anyway?

Comment: addResourceHandler is a member of ResourceHandlerRegistry, while addResourceLocations is a member of ResourceHandlerRegistration which is the return type of ResourceHandlerRegistry.addResourceHandler itself... Please refer to the docs here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ResourceHandlerRegistry.html

Comment: One maps the URL the other the place to get resources - just because you map both the same, doesn't mean everyone does. In fact, it would probably make more sense to map your CSS to `/css/**` for example.

Comment: "_these resource locations are supposed to be the subfolders of the URL_" - no. They are the locations of where to serve resources _from_ - i.e. the local path.

Answer (score 2):

`addResourceHandler` accepts URL **pattern** that you are going to use in your view pages.

> `addResourceHandler (java.lang.String... pathPatterns)`
>
> Add a resource handler for serving static resources based on the
>    specified URL path patterns. The handler will be invoked for every
>    incoming request that matches to one of the specified path patterns.

And on the other hand, in your `addResourceLocations` you specify the **actual specific location** of your resources. Spring will look into this folder or location to resolve the resources whose url pattern will match.

> `addResourceLocations(java.lang.String... resourceLocations)`
>
> Add one or more resource locations from which to serve static content. Each location must point to a valid directory. Multiple
>   locations may be specified as a comma-separated list, and the
>   locations will be checked for a given resource in the order specified.

### Example

To understand the differences between them consider the following example. If you configure

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/res/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
```

then you can use them in your view like this

```
<link href="res/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Notice that your *ResourceHandler* is configured to the URL pattern `res/**` (you could map it to something else) and any resource request that match this pattern will be handled by the handler.

Like the request for `res/css/main.css`, Spring MVC will get matched it with that handler and will ask that handler to resolve it. Then the handler will try to find the `main.css` file in the actual resource location you configured to `/resources/`.

**More to read**

- Method Detail [addResourceHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ResourceHandlerRegistry.html#addResourceHandler-java.lang.String...-)
- Method Detail  [addResourceLocations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ResourceHandlerRegistration.html#addResourceLocations-java.lang.String...-)